# What is an effective way of acquiring the Demolition Derby achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

This challenge requires you to get a chain of destroying 50 breakable objects. So far in the game, I have not been able to find any area that has that many objects close together. Is there a particular area that you find is good for getting this achievement? Any other tips?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cemetery of the Forsaken is a pretty nice place with relatively few enemies.  Just go around in a circle, keep your rhythm, and don't forget you can smash those stone column things near stairs.  Use those columns to hop between the gravestone patches.

Also, having a skill such as Leap or some other kind of teleport will help you keep the rhythm if you accidentally end up too far away from your next target.

I recommend using a close-range melee attack.  AoE attacks are not recommended because you might end up in an empty area that you created.  If you use skills that consume your resource, make sure you have as much as possible and can easily regenerate it by, for example, attacking the skeletons in the area.

Using +movement speed gear is also very helpful.

Comment: Got it on my 5th try. Start from just to the east of waypoint to the north of the chasm. Go anticlockwise and back to just south of the same chasm.

Comment: But what skill are you using to destroy them? Trying to figure out how to not run out of fury while spinning

Comment: @Fredy31 I just used Frenzy and Leap.  If you want to keep Fury up, there is a passive ability called Unforgiving (level 55) that helps, and there is a Whirlwind rune that decreases Fury usage.  Other than that, just stack +Max Fury equipment.  I do not recommend using Fury skills for this, but it certainly is possible with the right amount of skill.  You can use the enemies in the area to help you regenerate Fury, also.

Comment: Great! Just done it. Shift-Click to attack without enemies was a great help... just keep an eye out for these skeletons... they have are good at destroying that tombstone you needed to continue the combo.

Comment: @Fredy31 If you are playing a DH like me, multishot is your friend.

Comment: I used a monk with: Tempest rush and 13 spirit regeneration per second.

Answer (score 10):

I found royal crypts to be much easier with all of the ash pots. I failed at around 20 items and still ended up with a 63 streak.

Comment: This is especially easy with movement speed up skills to connect the initial 26+ to the remaining ones. I find it helps to quickly run through and take out the skeletons near the corner with the waypoint before starting so that they don't take out some destructibles. Got it this way on my 3rd try with a Barbarian using Sprint. I can see this working with the other speed+ skills as well.

Answer (score 3):

To get this achievement, I recommend to use a Demon Huntress with the Skills:

- Elemental Arrow, Rune Ball Lightning.
- Vault
- Preparation

Go to the Forsaken Cemetary and use your Ball Lightning. The Lightning travels rather slow, spreading the destruction of the tombstones and other destructible over a considerable amount of time. Move around the cemetary quickly using Vault and set of Balls of Lightning in different positions around the central pavillon. This should very easily generate this achievement.

Another Option is to go to the Royal Crypts and run through it using Ball Lightning as you run/vault.  It took me 1 try with the above method.

Narrow hallways & 12+% Run speed boots are the key to success.

Answer (score -1):

Use sweeping wind, spend 50k on two regen 1h and get all the regen passive + templar with regen skill, run in a circle in forsaken cemetary, refresh sweeping wind as needed. got it first try after switching to my wiz

Comment: You've got a huge run-on sentence going. You should try to split the sentences uses proper punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

i got this achievement with my barb by wearing the Fire Walkers boots and using the Sprint skill. 
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers
Took me a few tries but i finally got it

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a complete answer. The essense of this question is WHERE you got your achievement.

Answer (score -1):

Demon Hunter - grave yard - multi arrow. It will take you about 5 seconds.  Use vault to get to the next set faster.

Comment: Multishot is the name of the skill, not multi arrow. I'd like to see a video of you doing this in five seconds. That just sounds implausible.

Answer (score -2):

Cemetary of the Forsaken with my wizard, used chain lightning with up to 6 objects rune, np at all